# pq: SSL is not enabled on the server

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx, pq

I'm using `SET DSN="postgres://postgres:password@127.0.0.1/food_db_development?sslmode=disable"` and `SET GIN_PORT=":7070"` and when trying to run my **main.go** file i just get the error ***pq: SSL is not enabled on the server***
Does anyone know how to solve it? I saw other people with the same problem but some didn't use SQLX or had some differences that even when trying to adapt to my code didn't give any results.

My main.go code file ->

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type Config struct {
    Dsn     string `required:"true"`
    GinPort string `required:"true" split_words:"true"`
}

func LoadConfig() (*Config, error) {
    var c Config
    err := envconfig.Process("", &c)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to load config: %w", err)
    }
    return &c, nil
}

func NewPostgresDB(conf *Config) (*sqlx.DB, error) {
    db, err := sqlx.Connect("postgres", conf.Dsn)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return db, nil
}

func main() {
    conf, err := LoadConfig()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println("configurations: ", conf)
    db, err := NewPostgresDB(conf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println("connected to db with: ", db)
}
```

i'm using postgres and password as default username/password

I get the first one right but the second one not:

`2023/11/09 20:07:31 configurations:  &{"postgres://postgres:password@127.0.0.1/food_db_development?sslmode=disable" ":7070"}`
and
`2023/11/09 20:07:31 pq: SSL is not enabled on the server`

Comment: `SSL is not enabled on the server` indicates to  me that  `ssl` is set to `off` here [SSL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SSL). Not sure why that would trigger with `sslmode=disable`. I would look at the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the server.  Maybe the client/driver is overriding the setting?

Comment: Please try `db, err := sqlx.Connect("postgres", "postgres://postgres:password@127.0.0.1/food_db_development?sslmode=disable")` directly. It's very likely that there is a typo in `sslmode=`. If  there is a typo, the parameter will be omitted and by default, the sslmode is `require`.

Comment: What happens if you call `psql "postgres://postgres:password@127.0.0.1/food_db_development?sslmode=disable"` from your terminal?